# What is the meaning of leaf node of J48 tree classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, decision-tree, j48

[image: sample picture]
I am unable to understand the meaning of leaf node attribute of decision tree.

I am a new machine learner and after classifying the dataset by using J48 algo.I got a tree and now I'm unable to understand which attribute's value is related with tree's leaf node.
I'm simply perform a prediction by using dataset from Kaggle.

Comment: Unclear. Any samples?

Comment: click on sample picture and you'll get sample@NikolayShevchenko

Answer (score 0):

Majority class, and class frequencies.

These values are useful for estimating the certainty of the classifier.

Comment: Thanks for your support @Anony-Mousse. But what is the meaning of the paranthesis containing values?  Like(3.0/1.0)